# How to use the JDA getUserById function

Tags: java, discord

I am working in Java on a Discord Bot, and I have a command that adds the DiscordID of the user that sends a message to a database. With another command, I try to retrieve this data to output it. However, I can't seem to get the user if the ID is different from the user issuing the command. I have retrieved the user IDs I need and put them in an ArrayList, and then I try to do the following:

`User user = jda.getUserById(id);`

Here, `id` is obtained from the ArrayList. If this ID matches the ID of the user that is sending the command, it will go fine. But, if it is the ID of another user, that did not issue the command, it will simply return null. I am sure that the ArrayList contains the correct information.

Is the getUserById function limited to the user that issues the command? And if so, how could I bypass this to get any user from their ID, regardless of who sends the message?

*Example*

I've added the needed data from two different users, so the ArrayList contains two different Discord ID's.

```
User userName = jda.getUserById(id);
System.out.println(userName);
```

The following is returned when issuing the command from xAur0ra's account:

```
U:xAur0ra(myID)
null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDA.html#getUserById(long)) explains: **This will only check cached users!**

This means the user is simply not cached at the time. You can use the [retrieveUserById](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDA.html#retrieveUserById(long)) and [User.fromId](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/User.html#fromId(long)) methods to get a user for the specific use-case you want.

**Example**

```java
jda.retrieveUserById(userId).queue(user -> {
    System.out.println(user);
});
```

Comment: I have failed to find these other functions when searching for a solution, but using the retrieveUserById did the trick for me! The lambda expression did not work, because it says that the .queue couldn't be resolved in 'User'.

Comment: That was a typo, fixed