# How to get username by message id

Tags: java, events, discord-jda

I am facing a problem that I can't find out the username from the id of his message, I have tried many ways but I still can't do it, please help me.

I have no idea how to do this (second day learning JDA - Java Discord API)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use the JDA getUserById function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65357706/how-to-use-the-jda-getuserbyid-function). The same method/API call should work in the current version "5" of JDA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U need the TextChannel or PrivateChannel too...

```
channel.retrieveMessageById(id).queue((message) -> {
     User u = message.getAuthor();

     //only in TextChannels on Guilds
     Member m = message.getMember();
}
```

I hope I could help you :)